# How to write ternary operator with out else using ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

currently in my code if data is there i was displaying the details like (year, title, registration and location), if no data then I am displaying **no data available** message under Prime section, Now i want to hide the entire section with details if no data available.

```
 const WpPrime = ({
      translate, memberships, otherDetails, selectedTemplate,
    }) => (
      <section className="prime-section">
        <p className="section-title">
          {(otherDetails.section_title
            && otherDetails.section_title.prime)
        || translate('Premier')}
        </p>
        {Array.isArray(memberships) && memberships.length > 0 ? (
          memberships
            .sort((a, b) => b.year - a.year)
            .map(item => (
              <div key={item.year || item.title} className={`two-column-section date-alignment-${otherDetails && otherDetails.date_alignment}`}>
                <p className="section-sub-title" style={{ color: getColor(selectedTemplate) }}>
                  {item.year}
                </p>
                <div className="section-description">
                  <p className="section-title-description" style={{ color: getColor(selectedTemplate), fontWeight: '700' }}>
                    {item.title}
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    {item.registration ? ` ${item.registration}` : ''},
                    &nbsp;{item.location}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
        ) : (
          <p className="section-description">{translate('dataNotAvailable')}</p>
        )}
      </section>
    );
```

Comment: Which one is the __entire section with details__ you want to hide... ?

Comment: {a === b ? jsx : null}

Comment: @Ergis entire section means as I mentioned in the question (Section name Prime  ,inside  these are the details(fields)(year, title, registration and location)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the && operator for this purpose. If the condition is true then it will display the data.

```
    const WpPrime = ({
  translate,
  memberships,
  otherDetails,
  selectedTemplate,
}) => (
  <section className="prime-section">
    {Array.isArray(memberships) && memberships.length > 0 && (
      <>
        <p className="section-title">
          {(otherDetails.section_title && otherDetails.section_title.prime) ||
            translate("Premier")}
        </p>
        {memberships
          .sort((a, b) => b.year - a.year)
          .map((item) => (
            <div
              key={item.year || item.title}
              className={`two-column-section date-alignment-${
                otherDetails && otherDetails.date_alignment
              }`}
            >
              <p
                className="section-sub-title"
                style={{ color: getColor(selectedTemplate) }}
              >
                {item.year}
              </p>
              <div className="section-description">
                <p
                  className="section-title-description"
                  style={{
                    color: getColor(selectedTemplate),
                    fontWeight: "700",
                  }}
                >
                  {item.title}
                </p>
                <p>
                  {item.registration ? ` ${item.registration}` : ""}, &nbsp;
                  {item.location}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </>
    )}
  </section>
);
```

Comment: HI @Azhar Zafar, thanks for the response, I don't want to show the section name if no data is available, In our case, Premier (section name) is displaying, but we need to hide the name as well if no data available.

Comment: Alright. I updated the condition and now you can skip the section name as well.

Comment: Getting an error in aline "map" Unexpected parentheses around single function argument having a body with no curly braces  arrow-parens

Comment: Hi @Azhar Zafar, I resolved the issue by removing the extra braces in the map(item)

Answer (score 0):

Make the ternary operator for the whole section then:

```
<>
{Array.isArray(memberships) && memberships.length > 0 ? <section>...</section>:null}
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***null*** or <></> (React Fragment tag) in the else part.

```
{ your_condition ? render_what_you_want : null}
```

or

```
{ your_condition ? render_what_you_want : <></>}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const WpPrime = ({
  translate,
  memberships,
  otherDetails,
  selectedTemplate,
}) => (
  <section className="prime-section">
    {Array.isArray(memberships) && memberships.length > 0 && (
      <>
        <p className="section-title">
          {(otherDetails.section_title && otherDetails.section_title.prime) ||
            translate("Premier")}
        </p>
        {memberships
          .sort((a, b) => b.year - a.year)
          .map(item => (
            <div
              key={item.year || item.title}
              className={`two-column-section date-alignment-${
                otherDetails && otherDetails.date_alignment
              }`}
            >
              <p
                className="section-sub-title"
                style={{ color: getColor(selectedTemplate) }}
              >
                {item.year}
              </p>
              <div className="section-description">
                <p
                  className="section-title-description"
                  style={{
                    color: getColor(selectedTemplate),
                    fontWeight: "700",
                  }}
                >
                  {item.title}
                </p>
                <p>
                  {item.registration ? ` ${item.registration}` : ""}, &nbsp;
                  {item.location}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </>
    )}
  </section>
);
```